# Definition of nowhere differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Is there a formal definition for the concept of **nowhere differentiable function** in $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that a function can fail to be differentiable in several ways in an open interval but I am looking for references.
I am also familiar with the most common examples.

Comment: It is a function $f : \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that there is no $a\in\Bbb R$ where the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ exists. An easy class of examples is the set of functions which are nowhere continuous. [This](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function exists but it is nontrivial to show that it is nowhere differentiable. The Weierstraß function 
$$W:\mathbf R \to \mathbf R, \quad W(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbf N}b^k \cos (a^k x)$$
for $0<b<1$ and $ab>1+\frac{3\pi}{2}$, where $a\in\mathbf N$, $a\neq 0$ and $b\in\mathbf R$ is continuous but **nowhere** differentiable. The idea to show this is by contradiction, using fourier methods and some growing conditions. If you like I can post the idea later in more detail.

The picture shows the partial sum of $W$ with $\alpha= 0.5$

[image: Partial sum of $W$ with $\alpha= 0.5$.]

Comment: It's trivial to obtain a nowhere differentiable function (say, a function which is $0$ on $\Bbb Q$ and $1$ on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$), but it is nontrivial to construct a *continuous* nowhere differentiable function (which is what the Weierstraß function is.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am familiar with the Weierstraß function. I am looking for a class of formal definitions.

Comment: @Stahl Thank you. I added it!